# Determine the CASCADE DELETE paths that prevent the addition of a new cascade delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have many tables in my SQL database with a large number of foreign key relationships using cascade delete. I've determined that an existing relationship now requires cascade delete. Attempting to enable this gives the helpful message:

```
Unable to create relationship Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint on table may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

However, it doesn't mention the other paths through the set of tables that would cause the creation of a cyclic relationship; it simply dodges the issue by saying:

```
modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints
```

I do not want to make changes in Entity Framework as we are working model-first.

How can I see the relevant competing foreign key relationships?

Comment: Manually implementing the cascade delete in an delete trigger could probably be a workaround. Because who care if it's cyclic, in the end, it's can't delete more data then there is in the database. However, it might be slow if it cycle too deeply.

Comment: I do not need to suffer the performance hit of a trigger. I need to determine the foreign keys that contribute to the cyclic relationship so I can deterministically adjust them to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not dodging anything.  One presumes you have something resembling an entity-relationship (ER) diagram somewhere, whereby the newcomer can IMMEDIATELY grasp the foreign key relationships and why they are the way they are.

Were you working "model first," as you say, you wouldn't be finding that you have to "switch horses in mid-stream" after you've already (apparently) BUILT something.  (That's what CREATE TABLE says to me: you BUILT something.)

Comment: We do have an ER diagram although it is a very small subset of the DB tables. Are you suggesting that adding the navigation property via the edmx file will tell me WHICH navigation properties and their tables are the reason for the cyclic relationship? That's the key information to which this question relates.